# Recognizing worth without sounding condescending

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, phrase-request, synonyms

I am writing a sort of proposal for a scholarship and I am thinking of how to write the final paragraph.

At the moment I have in mind that perhaps I should mention something along the lines of

> I am **appreciative** of your program

The funding body is a bank, and therefore could *afford* not funding anyone's university fees). The problem is that everything I come up doesn't sound half as humble as it ought to (e.g. verbs 'acknowledge', 'recognise').

I don't think saying that I am 'grateful' works either since this would be the sort of thing you say once you have already been accepted/ asked to interview.

Comment: Instead of "I am appreciative of...", try "I appreciate..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about: "I place great value on your program"?  It shows that you think the programme is a worthy, valuable one, which is the same as recognition. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"I appreciate the valuable contribution your support would have toward helping me reach my educational goals."

Comment: This is flowery, and I find it hard to even understand what you’re trying to say. I’d much prefer something more to-the-point, like: _I appreciate your support toward helping me reach my educational goals._

Comment: Your suggested verbiage ^ would only be properly used once funding is promised.  Flowery?  Then I suppose successful grant writing is "flowery" by its very nature.  Whatever it takes to get the money, lol.

Comment: You're right about my statement sounding premature. I'd still simplify, though: _Any support toward helping me reach my educational goals would be greatly appreciated_.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I imagine how 'flowery' (without any negative connotations) you make it also depends on whether it's a UK or American application, among other things